# Emojis turns into ???? in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

### Hello Stack Overflow!

Since a year, my MySql database cannot receive any emojis, and turns them into question marks. I have seen some posts such as this one [Emoji's in mysql turns to question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385862/emojis-in-mysql-turns-to-question-marks) and many others that told me to `ALTER DATABASE db COLLATION` or `DELFAULT CHARACTER` but none of them seems to work.

[This is what I get for `show variables like 'char%'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28Ik.png)

I think the problem comes from the `character_set_server` variable with the latin1 value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you need to follow thorough for the `for each table` and `for each column` bits of the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emoji's in mysql turns to question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385862/emojis-in-mysql-turns-to-question-marks)

Comment: include the `show create table {tablename}` for the table that is meant to be showing the emojis

Comment: Chances are that the program you use to view data in MySQL is incapable of showing utfmb4 encoded data rather than MySQL not being able to store it.